# How to make hbox fit the column header?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

this is the code for custom column header:

```
private HBox createHeader(int index, String name){
        HBox box = new HBox();
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        TextField headerTextField = new TextField(name);
        headerTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            changeHeaderList(oldValue, newValue);
        });


        final ImageView crossImg = new ImageView("file:res/x.png");
        crossImg.setFitHeight(20d);
        crossImg.setFitWidth(20d);
        crossImg.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent event) -> {
            selectedMatrix.getMatrixRowsArrList().forEach((MatrixRow mr) -> mr.getCells().remove(index));
            selectedMatrix.setNumOfColumns(selectedMatrix.getNumOfColumns() - 1);
            showMatrix(selectedMatrix.getName());
            event.consume();
        });

        box.getChildren().addAll(headerTextField, crossImg);
        return box;
    }
```

This is how it is called:

```
if (editBox.isSelected()) {

    col.setSortable(false);                       
    col.setGraphic(createHeader(i, m.getMatrixRowsArrList().get(0).getCells().get(i)));
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

In fullscreen:

[image]

How can I make TextField to stretch across whole HBox? So it is filled in fullscreen like in the first picture. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [HGrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) in the createHeader method for your HBox:

```
HBox.setHgrow(headerTextField, Priority.ALWAYS);
```